# Time based window function in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

My goal is to calculate another column, keeping the same number of rows as the original DataFrame, where I can show the mean balance for each user for the last 30 days.

I guess it can be done using Window Functions, partitioning by user and somehow limiting the rows which are between the current date and 30 days before, but I don't know how to implement it in PySpark.

I have the following Spark DataFrame:

| userId | date | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 09/06/2020 | 100 |
| A | 03/07/2020 | 200 |
| A | 05/08/2020 | 600 |
| A | 30/08/2020 | 1000 |
| A | 15/09/2020 | 500 |
| B | 03/01/2020 | 100 |
| B | 05/04/2020 | 200 |
| B | 29/04/2020 | 600 |
| B | 01/05/2020 | 1600 |

My desired output DataFrame would be:

| userId | date | balance | mean_last_30days_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 09/06/2020 | 100 | 100 |
| A | 03/07/2020 | 200 | 150 |
| A | 05/08/2020 | 600 | 600 |
| A | 30/08/2020 | 1000 | 800 |
| A | 15/09/2020 | 500 | 750 |
| B | 03/01/2020 | 100 | 100 |
| B | 05/04/2020 | 200 | 200 |
| B | 29/04/2020 | 600 | 400 |
| B | 01/05/2020 | 1600 | 800 |

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql import types as T

data = [("A",datetime.strptime("09/06/2020",'%d/%m/%Y'),100),
        ("A",datetime.strptime("03/07/2020",'%d/%m/%Y'),200),
        ("A",datetime.strptime("05/08/2020",'%d/%m/%Y'),600),
        ("A",datetime.strptime("30/08/2020",'%d/%m/%Y'),1000),
        ("A",datetime.strptime("15/09/2020",'%d/%m/%Y'),500),
        ("B",datetime.strptime("03/01/2020",'%d/%m/%Y'),100),
        ("B",datetime.strptime("05/04/2020",'%d/%m/%Y'),200),
        ("B",datetime.strptime("29/04/2020",'%d/%m/%Y'),600),
        ("B",datetime.strptime("01/05/2020",'%d/%m/%Y'),1600)]

schema = T.StructType([T.StructField("userId",T.StringType(),True),
                       T.StructField("date",T.DateType(),True), 
                       T.StructField("balance",T.StringType(),True)
                      ])
 
sdf_prueba = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
sdf_prueba.printSchema()
sdf_prueba.orderBy(F.col('userId').asc(),F.col('date').asc()).show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `RANGE BETWEEN` keyword:

```
sdf_prueba.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")

spark.sql(
    """SELECT *, mean(balance) OVER (
        PARTITION BY userid 
        ORDER BY CAST(date AS timestamp)  
        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 30 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
     ) AS mean FROM table1""").show()


+------+----------+-------+-----+
|userId|      date|balance| mean|
+------+----------+-------+-----+
|     A|2020-06-09|    100|100.0|
|     A|2020-07-03|    200|150.0|
|     A|2020-08-05|    600|600.0|
|     A|2020-08-30|   1000|800.0|
|     A|2020-09-15|    500|750.0|
|     B|2020-01-03|    100|100.0|
|     B|2020-04-05|    200|200.0|
|     B|2020-04-29|    600|400.0|
|     B|2020-05-01|   1600|800.0|
+------+----------+-------+-----+
```

If you want to use the `pyspark` API, you need to
convert days to unix seconds in order to use `rangeBetween`

```
one_month_in_seconds = 2629743 # ?
w = (
    Window.partitionBy("userid")
    .orderBy(unix_timestamp(col("date").cast("timestamp")))
    .rangeBetween(-one_month_in_seconds, Window.currentRow)
)

sdf_prueba.select(col("*"), mean("balance").over(w).alias("mean")).show()

+------+----------+-------+-----+
|userId|      date|balance| mean|
+------+----------+-------+-----+
|     A|2020-06-09|    100|100.0|
|     A|2020-07-03|    200|150.0|
|     A|2020-08-05|    600|600.0|
|     A|2020-08-30|   1000|800.0|
|     A|2020-09-15|    500|750.0|
|     B|2020-01-03|    100|100.0|
|     B|2020-04-05|    200|200.0|
|     B|2020-04-29|    600|400.0|
|     B|2020-05-01|   1600|800.0|
+------+----------+-------+-----+
```

Comment: It works perfectly. I just have a question about why you use the number 2629743, since 30 days would be =  30*24*60*60 seconds, and that is: 2592000 seconds

Comment: Because it takes unix timestamp with off head its 30.44 days. Are you able to accept the answer please?

Comment: But how did you come up with this number? What if for example I wanted 25 days? Is there any formula to calculate this number of seconds?

Comment: Enter that into an online calculator, sincerely thats what I did

Comment: @javier-monsalve since you start from dates, I think any number between 30*24*3600 and (31*24*3600-1) should be fine...

Comment: How do we find the rolling window ? My date range window is last day of previous month and -12 months from last Date of previous month